# SOAP Client - how to to correctly create request?

Tags: php, soap, soap-client

I'm trying to connect to the SOAP server and call one from his methods named: 
**GetContactPerson**

For testing I'm using SoapUI who generate example request for me :

```
<soap:Header/>
 <soap:Body>
  <v2:GetReferencedDataRequest version="2.0.0">
     <v2:authentication>USERNAME:PASSWORD</v2:authentication>
     <!--Optional:-->
     <v2:payload>
        <!--Optional:-->
        <v2:extensionPoint>WHATS SHOULD I PUT HERE ?</v2:extensionPoint>
     </v2:payload>
  </v2:GetReferencedDataRequest>
</soap:Body>
```

Response from server after sending that request :

```
Could not unmarshal SOAP message due to invalid request: Unable to create an 
instance of *.model.v20.PayloadType
```

I know that this is a error, but I don't know what shout I put between tags : `<v2:extensionPoint>`

From documentation XSD I have :

```
<xsd:complexType name="PayloadType" abstract="true">
    <xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:documentation xml:lang="en">The payload is the base type of the business content of a request or response.</xsd:documentation>
    </xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="extensionPoint" type="xsd:anyType" minOccurs="0">
            <xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:documentation xml:lang="en">Generic extension point</xsd:documentation>
            </xsd:annotation>
        </xsd:element>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

Ok, but now I'm trying to send request from PHP.
First I'm fireing method : `$client->__getFunctions();`

Result : 
`GetContactPersonResponse GetContactPerson(GetContactPersonRequest $GetContactPersonRequest)`

From documentation :

```
<xsd:element name="GetContactPersonRequest">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:complexContent>
            <xsd:extension base="GetCustomerReferencingEntityRequestType"/>
        </xsd:complexContent>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

E.q code :

```
$client = new SoapClient( $wsdlAddress, [
 'login' => 'PlainText',
 'password' => 'PlanText',
 'soap_version' => SOAP_1_2
] );

$someTest = $client->GetContactPerson( $params );
```

How correctly create request from php? 
How to create `$params` that should be `GetContactPersonRequest` type ?

Answer (score 0):

The best and simpliest way to construct a SOAP request is to use a WSDL to PHP generator. In addition, it'll ease you the handling of the response,

Take a look to the [PackageGenerator](https://github.com/WsdlToPhp/PackageGenerator) project